# Android AdMob now showing on my phone

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to put AdMob add to my phone, i registered on admob website and i got green dot for status saying Active, but when i run app on my phone, add is nowhere to be seen. I googled a lot, but everything i tried didn't get me any result.

here is what i had put in my main layout xml file :

```
     <com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="a15176e8a6c0467"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hr.sv.mate.crypt"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
    </uses-permission>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="hr.sv.mate.crypt.MySmsRecivier" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="hr.sv.mate.crypt.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

and this is how i call add from main activity:

```
        adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a15176e8a6c0467");
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
    mainLayout.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

but still nothing shows, i tried changing code above in a few different versions thinking "maybe i called add wrong" but nothing helped.  Can anybody find what did i do wrong in here ?

Comment: Did you check your logcat? It may be that your app is calling ads correctly but it's not showing because you are testing on an emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR)` and see if a banner shows up: if it does it's not a problem, just remove that line before publishing and everything will be all right; if it doesn't it an issue of AdMob's servers, just wait for Google engineers to solve them.

Comment: Well i think you helped me, i used you code but instead of AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR , put my phone id and it still didn't show until i put it in landscape mode .. i looks like there isn't enough space in portrait .. anyway thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ads to auto refreshing via the AdMOB website.